# AADSTS90094: "The grant requires admin permission " but admin consent but was already granted

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a multi-tenant native app that calls device information from the Microsoft Graph. There is no Web API between the native app and the Microsoft Graph. The scopes being requested are: User.Read, Directory.Read.All, Device.Read

From the customer tenant, the customer admin has granted permissions to the app using the following URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant Domain}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={ClientID Of App}&response_type=code&prompt=admin_consent
```

After completing, the return has the consented value as TRUE and the app appears in Azure AD -> Enterprise Applications -> All Applications -> {App Name} with the "permissions" section showing all 3 permissions against Microsoft Graph as "Delegated" and Granted by "An administrator".

When the admin of the customer tenant logs into the app afterward, the app works as expected. However, if a non-admin user tries to log into the app, they receive an error after logging in:

> Need admin approval - {App name} needs permission to access resources
>   in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin
>   to grant permission to this app before you can use it. Message:
>   AADSTS90094: The grant requires admin permission.

Again, the admin has already consented to the app.

Additionally, the app manifest in the developer company's tenant shows in Azure AD -> App registrations -> (Filter of "All Apps" -> {App Name} -> Manifest shows:

```
{
    "appId": "{Hidden from StackOverflow}",
    "appRoles": [],
    "availableToOtherTenants": true,
    "displayName": "{Hidden from StackOverflow}",
    "errorUrl": null,
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "homepage": null,
    "informationalUrls": {
        "privacy": null,
        "termsOfService": null
    },
    "identifierUris": [],
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "objectId": "{Hidden from StackOverflow}",
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [],
    "publicClient": true,
    "replyUrls": [
        "{Hidden from StackOverflow}"
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [{
        "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
        "resourceAccess": [{
                "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "06da0dbc-49e2-44d2-8312-53f166ab848a",
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "11d4cd79-5ba5-460f-803f-e22c8ab85ccd",
                "type": "Scope"
            }
        ]
    }],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null
}
```

The relevant code:

```
public static async Task<Device> GetDeviceByName(string DeviceName)
{
    IGraphServiceDevicesCollectionPage result = await AuthHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient().Devices.Request().GetAsync();
    foreach (Device device in result)
    {
        if (device.DisplayName == DeviceName)
        {
            return device;
        }
    }

    return new Device();
}

static string ClientId = "{Hidden from StackOverflow}";
public static string[] Scopes = { "User.Read", "Directory.Read.All", "Device.Read" };
public static string TokenForUser = null;
public static PublicClientApplication IdentityClientApp =
    new PublicClientApplication(ClientId, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations");

private static GraphServiceClient graphClient = null;

public static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
{
    if (graphClient == null)
    {
        graphClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async(requestMessage) =>
            {
                var token = await GetTokenForUserAsync();
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

            }));
    }

    return graphClient;
}

public static async Task<string> GetTokenForUserAsync()
{
    AuthenticationResult authResult;

    try
    {
        authResult = await IdentityClientApp
            .AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes, IdentityClientApp.Users.First());
    }
    catch
    {
        authResult = await IdentityClientApp
            .AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes);
    }

    TokenForUser = authResult.AccessToken;

    return TokenForUser;
}

public static void SignOut()
{
    foreach (var user in IdentityClientApp.Users)
    {
        IdentityClientApp.Remove(user);
    }

    graphClient = null;
    TokenForUser = null;
}
```

I have been working on this for about a week and I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I have looked at a ton of documents on learn.microsoft.com related to this and most examples use Web API.

Comment: Could you include an example of the token you're receiving?

Comment: When I call IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes); the login screen appears in the native app. The non-admin user logs in and cannot proceed past being asked for their password. They close the login window (or choose the link to return to the app without giving consent) and the app returns authResult as null. So no token gets generated.

Comment: If the tenant admin logs in from the IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes); call, the received access token is: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFCSGg0a21TX2FLVDVYcmp6eFJBdEh6Q1dzRmhGZmxxZF8yY3gtMlZrS3dXUnhYd093ZDAxUlEyUkZ1NmR2S21CVkNJcTgzNzNsUFhXczV5OVF4dUhaQlVKdDlTWXR2WkUzb0Y2d3FzWlI5Q2lBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiU1NRZGhJMWNLdmhRRURTSnhFMmdHWXM0MFEwIiwia2lkIjoiU1NRZGhJMWNLdmhRRURTSnhFMmdHWXM0MFEwIn0.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2dyYXBoLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20iLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3N0cy53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC9jYzliYTgxNS1jNDk5L... (can't add more as stackoverflow is limiting characters)

Comment: When a normal user is logging in, are you passing anything related to `admin_consent`? for example in the URL you shared, you are passing `&prompt=admin_consent`. You need to make sure to only pass that parameter the one time the admin needs to consent. Beyond that, the user should never get that querystring, or the call will fail.

Comment: The &prompt=admin_consent only appears on the URL that is generated for the tenant Admin. It does not appear on the URL during a non-admin user authentication. (unless PublicClientApplication does that on it's own but I do not believe it does).

Comment: Does the Microsoft.Identity.Client and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Client.ActiveDirectory nugets support multi-tenant native apps? Should I roll my own authentication?

Comment: They absolutely should support multi-tenant native apps. Sanity check: are you 100% sure the Admin is from the same tenant as the regular user, and that the Admin consented for the tenant that the regular user was in?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it matters in this case, but isn't this the v1 endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant Domain}/oauth2/authorize`, and the code using the v2 endpoint via MSAL?

Comment: I agree with @juunas. Your manifest is for a v1 app but MSAL is for use with v2. You either need to register your app @ https://apps.dev.microsoft.com as a converged auth application or switch from MSAL to the older ADAL libary.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Yes, the admin is in the same tenant as the user.

Comment: @juunas I tried the converged auth application before posting on StackOverflow. It didn't seem to make a difference. The same issue occurs.

Comment: After looking further at the Nuget package site, I found out that one of the scopes I'm asking for is bugged. A bug report was filed by another user. It seems that the Device.Read is expected to work with a standard user account after an admin gives the grant but it doesn't work with the ASAL preview library. Until it's fixed my options are ADAL, or rolling my own.

Thanks to everyone for their help.